# Is random variable a way to search for actual input numbers?

Tags: random-variables

The formal definition of a random variable is

> Random variable over a sample space is a function from sample space to
>   $R$

I want to get intuitively what actually it is doing. In this context, I had the following idea

> A random variable is a method to search for actual input numbers (real numbers) for
>   the probability measure function. Since sample space is a set of
>   outcomes of a random experiment, they can be represented by any
>   symbols and assigns a probability for such outcomes. In order to get
>   the real numbers instead of symbols outcomes, we use random variables
>   so that probability measure becomes a real function. So there are good random variables and bad random variables.

Is it correct? Are random variable for making probability measure function a real valued function?

*From comments* I came to know that there may be no superiority of a random variable over another, if it is the case, then is it true that for a particular sample space, there is no particular assignment of outcomes to real numbers that is *desired inputs (for probability measure function) or useful in some way*?

Comment: You are missing *measurable* function.

Comment: I disagree with the conclusion "So there are good random variables and bad random variables."

Comment: "So there are good [...] and bad random vairables" seems unjustified

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean ranking among random variables, those provide good mapping (to actual real numbers) and others ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Maybe you refer to quantitative vs. qualitative values ? (say indexes assigned to colors)

Comment: @YvesDaoust didn't understand. But I mean that we can't treat all random variables on the same sample space equally. Suppose if random variable is a constant function, then it may not be a good random variable at all.

Comment: I don't think this is a problematic issue. In general, the definition of the r.v. comes naturally.

Comment: @hanug, There's nothing wrong with [a constant random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution). If there were, we couldn't say the random variables are closed under addition.

Comment: Often in applications we want to estimate or predict the value of some quantity such as the selling price of a house. We don't know the value of this quantity, but we do know that some values are more likely than other values. So this quantity is a random variable.